# Constructor with extra template argument

Tags: c++, templates

This question seems very closely related to the following, yet I do not fully understand it yet.

- [Can the template parameters of a constructor be explicitly specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2861839/653152)
- [Template constructor in a class template - how to explicitly specify template argument for the 2nd parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13002368/653152)

---

I want to have a template class that does something non-trivial in the constructor, depending on another template type. A minimal example would be this here:

```
template <typename A>
class Class {
  public:
    template <typename B>
    Class();

  private:
    int i;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
Class<A>::Class() {
    B b;

    i = b.get_number();
}
```

That does not compile with GCC:

```
$ env LC_ALL=C g++ --std=c++11 -c template.cpp 
template.cpp:14:1: error: prototype for 'Class<A>::Class()' does not match any in class 'Class<A>'
 Class<A>::Class() {
 ^~~~~~~~
template.cpp:7:5: error: candidate is: template<class A> template<class B> Class<A>::Class()
     Class();
     ^~~~~
```

Compiling with Clang gives other errors:

```
$ env LC_ALL=C clang++ --std=c++11 -c template.cpp 
template.cpp:13:1: error: too many template parameters in template redeclaration
template <typename A, typename B>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
template.cpp:3:1: note: previous template declaration is here
template <typename A>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I can get it to compile when I attach the template parameter `B` to the whole class.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class Class {
  public:
    Class();

  private:
    int i;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
Class<A, B>::Class() {
    B b;

    i = b.get_number();
}
```

Is there any way to contain the influence of template parameter `B` to the constructor? Or would I have to attach it to the whole class?

Comment: What is the point of such a constructor? You can never invoke it.

Comment: @Barry: That is now my follow-up question. I get a syntax error at `Class c<B>;`. So I need to inject some dummy variable in order to get the type deduced correctly?

Comment: @MartinUeding A question asked and answered in one of the questions you linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for the out-of-class **definition** of a `template` method in a `template` class is as follows:

```
template <typename A> // Class template parameters
template <typename B> // Method template parameters
Class<A>::Class() { 
//   ^^^
//   Class template parameters

    // ...
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HVCLEdE0y6T4SKoy)

Comment: This also generalises to nested classes, `template <typename A> template <typename B> template <typename C> Outer<A>::Inner<B>::Method(C param)` etc

Comment: Very interesting! Now that part works! Thank you.